# Convergence of a Geometric random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_n \sim \mathcal{G} (\frac{\theta}{n})  \; \theta>0$ Show that $\frac{X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{L} \mathcal{E(\theta)}$

We calculated the cumulative distribution function

$F_n(x)= \mathbb{P}(Y_n<x)=\mathbb{P}(X_n<nx)= \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{[nx]}p_n(1-p_n)^{k-1}= 1- (1-p_n)^{[nx]}}$

My question is the following: why in the next step we differentiated two cases, the first one $[nx] \not\in \mathbb{N}$ is the second $[nx] \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is it because we don't know the low of $Y$?

Comment: Please provide the complete proof, so that we can answer in context. What is $Y_n$? What is $Y$? You are seeking to prove convervence in distribution, right?

Comment: Have you thought about showing $M_{X_n/n}(t)\longrightarrow \frac{\theta}{\theta-t}$ as $n$ approaches $+\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

To proceed, write
$$
1-(1-p_n)^{\lfloor nx\rfloor} = 1- \left(1-\frac\theta n\right)^{nx}\left(1-\frac\theta n\right)^{-\beta(n,x)},
$$
where $\beta(n,x) := nx - \lfloor nx\rfloor$. Since $0\leqslant \beta(n,x)\leqslant 1$ for all $n,x$ the limit of the above is $1-e^{-\theta}$, as was to be shown.

Comment: thank you for your answer. @Math1000